# How to stop Fat-Free PHP from converting 0 to null?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

```
$frequentFoodLog->value = $frequentFoodLog->value - 1;
```

When I execute the above code with `$frequentFoodLog->value = 1` it is automatically converting the 0 to a null. So when it outputs in the view it displays null instead of 0.

I have tried:

```
$frequentFoodLog->value = (int) $frequentFoodLog->value - 1;
```

As well, in the view:

```
{{ is_null(@frequentFoodLog->value) ? '0' : @frequentFoodLog->value}}
```

And:

```
<check if="{{ is_null(@logValue) }}">
   <set logValue="0"/>
</check>
```

With no luck.

Any ideas as to how to fix this? The property on the model is set as an int:

```
@property int    value
```

And is stored in the MySql database as INT(11).

Besides displaying in the view improperly (and my debugger) it still acts as a 0 when I perform arthritic against it as well as saves to the database as 0.

I have found a "solution", by converting the value before returning it. But I would prefer a better one:

```
print json_encode(
     [
         'ffid'   => $ffid,
         'action' => $action,
         'value'  => is_null($frequentFoodLog->value) ? '0' : $frequentFoodLog->value,
         'carbs'  => $carbs
     ]
);
```

Comment: A subtraction operation will not convert anything into a null in PHP: it will result in an integer or a float value... something elsewhere is probably mdifying the value

Comment: That is what i am starting to think. But oddly enough when the page loads the first time it displays as 0, so its only during updating the value that it changes it to null as opposed to when it first gets it from the database.

Comment: is the db field configured as NULLable in the database table?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Here is what I did:
1. On the php:
`$testObject = new stdClass();`
`$testObject->property = 0;`
`$f3->set('testing', $testObject);`
2. In the template:
`{{ @testing->property }}`
The result is 0 as it should be...

Comment: On the other hand what do you mean that you are converting your value before *returning it*? Because it seems that the switch of type of variable occurs somewhere between the value is set and when the value is returned. Are you sure it is F3 doing something wrong there? Can you set the value to 0 just before returning it and see if it works on the view side?

Comment: @george007 What I mean is after I set the value on property it gets returned as null. So at the end of the function where I return the value my solution thus far has to check if null and return '0'

Comment: @ikkez The field is not nullable

Comment: What is the class of `$frequentFoodLog`? Is it a DAO or a PDO?

Comment: @george007 FrequentFoodLog is PDO

Comment: Why do you need to change the value of the parameter of the PDO? If not to update DB, then my suggestion would be to [fetch the row as a stdClass object](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) and then play with it. Maybe that would help? You can also use [F3 data mappers](http://fatfreeframework.com/sql-mapper)...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112867/discussion-between-george007-and-jrquick).

Answer (score 0):

test it after you attached the value:

```
if (is_null($frequentFoodLog->value)) {
    $frequentFoodLog->value = 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using Fat-Free PHP to manage the view and it uses @ instead of $

Comment: The `@` seems to be some kind of templating engine thingy

Comment: Ok, so I removed that notice.

Comment: I added: `<check if="{{ is_null(@logValue) }}"><set logValue="0"/></check>`, still didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

For php code in templates use {~ ~} instead of {{ }}.

```
{{ @array.key }}

{~ echo $array['key'] ~}
```